# Microsoft Office OneNote C++ APIs?

Tags: c++, onenote

I was looking into modifying Microsoft Office OneNote contents via c++ programming. Specifically at using [Quick Filing Dialog Box Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff966471%28v=office.14%29.aspx). But all the examples available in there are for C#, I want to know whether API for C++ is available, if so where can I start to learn them. I just wanted to use that dialog box get the OneNote section and insert my content as a page in that section.

Answer (score 0):

As [Daniel Escapa writes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2007/02/06/creating-a-c-c-add-in-which-works-with-onenote.aspx):

> Open Visual Studio and create a new C++ project. For my example I am creating a Win32 Console App:
>
> Now I want to add the OneNote2007 header file, OneNote12.h. You can find that attached with this document. Make sure to copy it to the folder with your C++ source files as well as add it to your header files like this:
>
> Add a new #include for OneNote:

```
#include "OneNote12.h"
```

> Now just connect to OneNote like you would any other COM API. Please see here for an example:

```
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IApplication* piOneNote;

 

    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Application), NULL,

        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, __uuidof(IApplication), (void**)&piOneNote);

 

    if(piOneNote)

    {

        BSTR temp;        

        HRESULT hr = piOneNote->GetHierarchy(NULL, hsNotebooks, &temp);

        wprintf(L"%s", temp);

    }
```