# Microsoft Office OneNote 2013 C++ APIs?

Tags: c++, onenote

I would like to get the C++ header for OneNote 2013, 64 bits.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16913579/2549876), there is a link that has the C++ header for OneNote 12. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2011/08/24/c-c-add-ins-for-onenote-2010.aspx) is the header for OneNote 2010. I opened it and it says

```
/* Compiler settings for C:\Users\Varunsri\Desktop\ExeServer14.idl:
Oicf, W1, Zp8, env=Win32 (32b run), target_arch=X86 7.00.0555
```

1. Is there a similar header for OneNote 2013 64 bits?
2. If not, are there tools to generate it?