# Qt ActiveX and OneNote (desktop 2016 32bit)

Tags: qt, com, activex, onenote-api

Trying to export student exam results from excel to Student OneNote pages.

importing the excel data using QAxObject dynamic calls works flawlessly however a similar setup with OneNote yeilds unkown

[getHieracrchy Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/onenote/application-interface-onenote) below is the output of dumpdoc.exe :

```
void GetHierarchy (QString bstrStartNodeID, HierarchyScope hsScope, QString& pbstrHierarchyXmlOut, XMLSchema xsSchema)


QVariantList params = ...
onenote_object->dynamicCall("GetHierarchy(QString, HierarchyScope, QString&, XMLSchema)", params);
```

Implementation :

```
QAxObject* onenote = new QAxObject("OneNote.Application"); 
QString doc = onenote->generateDocumentation();
qDebug() << onenote->control(); // {dc67e480-c3cb-49f8-8232-60b0c2056c8e}

QVariantList params;
QString xml_out;
params << "" << 4 << xml_out << 0;
onenote->dynamicCall("GetHierarchy(QString, HierarchyScope, QString&, XMLSchema)", params);
```

Error

```
QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member GetHierarchy: Unknown error
```

I have tried running dumpcpp against the CLSID of the OneNote.Application and the registry entry for the typelib thinking it might be a type error for a none builtin Qt->COM type, but no output is produced.

```
dumpcpp -nometaobject -getfile {0EA692EE-BB50-4E3C-AEF0-356D91732725} -o onenote
```

I can manipulate the pages via [powershell](http://thebackend.info/powershell/2017/12/onenote-read-and-write-content-with-powershell/) and see the typelib reference in visual basic but want to access OneNote from C++.

Comment: Not sure, but the OneNote dispatch/automation/dynamic interface seems not to work properly. You should use the IAutomation instead, something like this in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913579/microsoft-office-onenote-c-apis

Comment: Sorry, I meant IApplication...